# Subtracting subsequent rows in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file like this:

```
15:03:06:373 s1 13 s2 17 s3 15 s4 11 s5 7  15:03:06:450
15:03:06:555 s1 13 s2 19 s3 18 s4 15 s5 9  15:03:06:656
15:03:06:762 s1 13 s2 19 s3 21 s4 19 s5 13 15:03:06:833
15:03:06:939 s1 13 s2 19 s3 21 s4 19 s5 13 15:03:07:013
```

How can I subtract the rows using awk or some scripting to get the result in which values in front of s1, s2 etc are subtracted between the rows (like row2-row1, row3-row2). The result will be:

```
15:03:06:373 s1 13 s2 17 s3 15 s4 11 s5 7 15:03:06:450
15:03:06:555 s1 0  s2 2  s3 3  s4 4  s5 2 15:03:06:656
15:03:06:762 s1 0  s2 0  s3 3  s4 4  s5 4 15:03:06:833
15:03:06:939 s1 0  s2 0  s3 0  s4 0  s5 0 15:03:07:013
```

Comment: Did you mean to have the absolute value of the subtraction? For example, you have 7 - 9 = 2, 9 - 13 = 4.

Comment: you need to show some effort!

Comment: no the actual value. Also negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{for(i=3;i<NF;i+=2) {t=$i;$i-=s[i];s[i]=t}}1' file

15:03:06:373 s1 13 s2 17 s3 15 s4 11 s5 7 15:03:06:450
15:03:06:555 s1 0 s2 2 s3 3 s4 4 s5 2 15:03:06:656
15:03:06:762 s1 0 s2 0 s3 3 s4 4 s5 4 15:03:06:833
15:03:06:939 s1 0 s2 0 s3 0 s4 0 s5 0 15:03:07:013
```

explanation and alignment are left as an exercise.